# integral of $\sin(\sqrt(ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e))$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How does one approach integrating:

$f(x)=\sin(\sqrt{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e})$?

I have tried with substitution, which yields the following. I am quite new to this complexity of integration, so please tell me if there are any mistakes.

$\displaystyle\int f(x)dx=\displaystyle\int \sin(\sqrt{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e})dx$

$u=\sqrt{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e}$

$\displaystyle\int f(x)dx=\displaystyle\int \sin(u)dx$

Next, try to write $dx$ as a function $du$ and $u$.

$du=\dfrac{4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d}{\sqrt{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e}}dx$

$du=\dfrac{4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d}{u}dx$

Here I get stuck, because I don't know what to do with the top part of the fraction to get rid of the remaining x's. I see that:

$4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d=\dfrac{d}{dx}u^2$,

but I am not sure what I can do with that.

Guidance is really appreciated.

**How I got to this integral**

For context, I am creating a model of a quad rotor drone. In this case simplified to a single continuously running motor. I will leave most of the physics formulas out of this and try to make things concise.

Angle of the drone under a single running motor in axis-angle representation.

$\underrightarrow{\theta}=\theta \underrightarrow{e},\lvert e\rvert=1$

$\underrightarrow{\theta}(t)=\dfrac{1}{2}t^2\ddot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}+t\dot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}(0)+\underrightarrow{\theta}(0)$, with $\ddot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}$ constant.

$\theta(t)=\sqrt{(\dfrac{1}{2}t^2\ddot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_x+t\dot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_x(0)+\underrightarrow{\theta}_x(0))^2+(\dfrac{1}{2}t^2\ddot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_y+t\dot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_y(0)+\underrightarrow{\theta}_y(0))^2+(\dfrac{1}{2}t^2\ddot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_z+t\dot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_z(0)+\underrightarrow{\theta}_z(0))^2}$

$\underrightarrow{e}(t)=\dfrac{\underrightarrow{\theta}(t)}{\theta(t)}$

Next, velocity of the drone, and where the complicated integral comes in.

Acceleration under the (constant) force of one rotor

$\underrightarrow{\alpha}=\dfrac{1}{m}\underrightarrow{F^{'}}=\dfrac{1}{m}(\cos(\theta)\underrightarrow{F}+\sin(\theta)(\underrightarrow{e}\times\underrightarrow{F})+\underrightarrow{e}(1-\cos(\theta))(\underrightarrow{e}\cdot\underrightarrow{F}))$

with $F$ the force applied by the rotor, and $F^{'}$ that force after it is rotated by $\underrightarrow{\theta}$.

Integrating this to obtain velocity

$\underrightarrow{v}=\dfrac{1}{m}\displaystyle\int\underrightarrow{a}(t)\underrightarrow{F}+\underrightarrow{b}(t)+\underrightarrow{c}(t)dt$, with

$\underrightarrow{a}(t)=\cos(\theta(t))$

$\underrightarrow{b}(t)=\sin(\theta(t))(\underrightarrow{e}(t)\times\underrightarrow{F})$

$\underrightarrow{c}(t)=\underrightarrow{e}(t)(1-\cos(\theta(t)))(\underrightarrow{e}(t)\cdot\underrightarrow{F})$

I approached the integral by splitting into the above three parts. This question is about integrating part a. In all its large form it looks like

$\displaystyle\int\underrightarrow{a}(t)dt=\displaystyle\int\cos(\sqrt{(\dfrac{1}{2}t^2\ddot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_x+t\dot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_x(0)+\underrightarrow{\theta}_x(0))^2+(\dfrac{1}{2}t^2\ddot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_y+t\dot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_y(0)+\underrightarrow{\theta}_y(0))^2+(\dfrac{1}{2}t^2\ddot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_z+t\dot{\underrightarrow{\theta}}_z(0)+\underrightarrow{\theta}_z(0))^2})dt$

Which I simplified to the original equation given in this question. (I now see that it's actually $\cos$ and not $\sin$, but it's all the same)

Comment: What makes you think that this integral can be solved (i.e. expressed with elementary functions)? Most integrals that contain both square roots and trigonometric functions can't.

Comment: Most integrals cannot be done analytically. Do you have any reason to believe that this integral is possible?

Comment: Okay, I was not aware. Let me add an addition to the post of how I got to this integral.

Comment: I formatted your post to make it look better, but while adding your changes, you again reverted it to the poor formatting. Please use \sin for $\sin$, \dfrac for making fractions bigger and \displaystyle for making integral signs bigger. Your vector signs are also not properly written. Use \vec{a} for $\vec{a}$.

Comment: I hope my later addition gives some context

Comment: Okay excuse me, I will do that

Comment: @LightYagami I think I have solved your issues. Regarding the vector arrow in the bottom, that is on purpose, because I found it was more readable with the derivative dots there as well. So unless you really want it at the top I would leave it like this.

Comment: @AartStuurman Thank you, but you can still make it better by using \sin(\sqrt{\cdots}) for $\sin(\sqrt{\cdots})$. Regarding your integral, I don't think it has a result in terms of elementary functions. For example there is no elementary closed form of $\displaystyle \int \sin(\sqrt{x^2+x}) dx$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2Bx%29%29).

Comment: @LightYagami I have been convinced that it is not possible to create an integral in my case. However, I need to determine the velocity and position of the drone from the acceleration I have. Maybe less of a math question, but would you recommend to approximate the integral? I am thinking by iteration using a small dt?

Answer (score 1):

**comment**
For example, consider $\int\sin\sqrt{x^4+1}\;dx$.  Change variables using $y^2 = x^4+1$ to get
$$
\int\frac{y\sin y}{2(y^2-1)^{3/4}}\;dy
$$
This integral probably is not an elementary function.  It is not known to Maple.  I did not find it in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik.